# "QtBluetooth" support in PySide2 (QT for python project)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyside2, pyside6

"QtBluetooth" module is supported in PyQT5, but it seems not supported in PySide2 (a.k.a QT for python);

- Is this conclusion I have reached correct?
- Is there any difference between PySide2 and PySide6 in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** Qt Bluetooth module is available in QT for Python (PySide6). Docs is also has [entries](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtBluetooth/index.html?highlight=bluetooth#pyside6-qtbluetooth) about it. Thanks for the update [Rida Shamasneh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/656035/rida-shamasneh)

- Yes, it is correct.
- Yes, [PySide6 docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/search.html?q=bluetooth) don't have an entry yet but actually an [initial commit](https://code.qt.io/cgit/pyside/pyside-setup.git/commit/sources/pyside6/PySide6?id=5580b0a273a2a7967bafbd3a065b43ed0463e214) pushed just 3 days ago :)

Comment: Thanks.
Yes. I think this will take sometime to release a new version.

Comment: I've tried today pySide6 (v6.2.0); I can see it contains QT Bluetooth module; but and it seems like it is not working fine regarding the Bluetooth; I have already have a working code with PyQT5 but I am having serious issues to port it to PySide6

Comment: Update: PySide6 contains python binding for QBluetooth module; I was also able to write a full BLE client with it. I tested it on Linux and Windows 10

Comment: Thanks, the answer is updated